# How to import a local GIT/Maven project/folder into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, egit

So I did git clone to get a maven project from a remote git repository. Great! I have been working in the command line, doing git pull, commit, etc. Great! Now I want to import this project into eclipse and be able to use git inside eclipse through the installed egit. So I did a:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

And after that I am able to import the project into eclipse through the regular:

```
Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace
```

But the GIT options do not appear under Team !!! :( :( :(

How do I import this project and have the git options at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, what you want to do is import the project as a Maven project directly. Then you don't have to do all the random command line stuff, plus you have the Maven integration in Eclipse with your dependencies and `pom.xml` kept up to date. (You need m2e installed for this.) Go to Import and select 'Existing Maven Projects':

[image]

Then, what you should do is enable eGit on the project. Right click the root of the project and select "Share Project" under "Teams".

[image]

Select Git and it will tell you that you can use the existing repo. Voila, you're done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Team > Share Project -> select the git project.